# Aligning columns

Tags: java, string, indentation

I need to make the output of the following strings displayed in columns:

```
 System.out.printf("Weight of Item 1: %10d%n", ITEM_1);
 System.out.printf("Weight of Item 2: %10d%n", ITEM_2);
 System.out.printf("Weight of Item 3: %10d%n", ITEM_3);
 System.out.printf("Total Weight Kilograms: %10d%n", totalWeightKilograms);
```

I can get the variables that are input into the string to shift to where I want. I can't get the text format before the variables. Basically, the output I get:

```
Weight of Item 1:         38
Weight of Item 2:         23
Weight of Item 3:         12
Total Weight Pounds:         73
```

What I want is:

```
   Weight of Item 1:         38
   Weight of Item 2:         23
   Weight of Item 3:         12
Total Weight Pounds:         73
```

I need the indentation(width) of the string as much I need it to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could put your `item`(s) and `String`(s) into array(s), and specify a format length with `%s` as long as your longest `String` (22 characters). Something like,

```
String[] msg = { "Weight of Item 1", "Weight of Item 2", "Weight of Item 3",
        "Total Weight Kilograms" };
int[] items = { ITEM_1, ITEM_2, ITEM_3, totalWeightKilograms };
for (int i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%22s: %10d%n", msg[i], items[i]);
}
```

Which outputs (as requested)

```
      Weight of Item 1:         38
      Weight of Item 2:         23
      Weight of Item 3:         12
Total Weight Kilograms:         73
```